# Table of contents and symbols

Tags: thesis

I write a thesis, I want to write a table of contents and then a table of symbols (consists of more than one page) and a table of abbreviations, with the use of the head of the page The word of contents appears in the second page header of the symbols (knowing I type the symbols in the form of a table consisting of two columns), how to get rid of the header is in the second content page

Comment: Take a look at the glossaries package.

Comment: Do you have more informations for (for example an MWE) or is your issue already solved? How?